# Title bar menu in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

I think most of us must have seen the command prompt(windows) and how when we open it and click on it's icon and it shows a menu. Can we do a similar thing with tkinter? This is not the normal menubar.

Here is an illustration of the command prompt one.

[image: Command Prompt Icon/Title Bar Menu]

Comment: There is a menu for tkinter, but i dont think there is such a popup menu comes when you press on the icon of the titlebar. There is a menubar and a menu item for tkinter. Check [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/python-tkinter-menu#:~:text=The%20Menu%20widget%20is%20used,bar%20of%20the%20parent%20window.)

Comment: Possible solution is to use `win32gui`.Like `AppendMenu`.I don't think tkinter could achieve that.

Comment: Its not really clear to me what are you asking for? Becaus if I use a rightclick on the titlebar I get a menu like this.

Comment: @Atlas435 Yes we do but can we edit that menu like add new menu items to it, secondly in command prompt the moment we left click the icon is when it appears so can we do it too?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yup I know that one already I wanted on of the command prompt types.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA ohk Well thats sad as i have made by whole application in tkinter.

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer you would need to craft a work around, because the icon isnt directly a part of your application. The icon is given to the window manager and therefore it appers in the window decoration. You could delete the decoration and write your own to achive this, for exampel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an exampel of a work around without the need of doing all your window management by your own. Of course it will need improvements but as a start: [Popup stolen from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014210/tkinter-app-adding-a-right-click-context-menu)

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def popup(event):
    popup_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)

def set_icon():
    global top, popup
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    top.overrideredirect(1)
    top.attributes('-topmost',True)
    offset = 30
    x,y = root.winfo_rootx(),root.winfo_rooty()-offset
    width, height = offset,offset
    top.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width,height, x,y))
    my_label = tk.Label(top, image=photo)
    my_label.pack(fill='both')
    global popup_menu
    popup_menu = tk.Menu(top, tearoff=0)
    popup_menu.add_command(label="Delete",
                           command=lambda :print('del'))
    popup_menu.add_command(label="Select All",
                           command=lambda :print('sel'))

    top.bind("<Button-1>", popup)

def grab(event):
    top.geometry(f'+{event.x+10}+{event.y+2}')

root=tk.Tk()

ico = Image.open('prac_img/p2.png')
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ico)
root.iconphoto(False,photo)
#root.wm_iconphoto(False,photo)
root.bind('<Configure>',grab)
root.update_idletasks()
set_icon()

root.mainloop()
```

Another way would be to code your own titlebar and the use of `overrideredirecr(1)` which will undecorate your window by the window manager of your system.

Comment: But what if the user, drags the window out? Mind if i make few edits to the code?

Comment: No, I just wanted to give a hint not a full exampel. Please, go for it if you like to.

Comment: Yes, you can. :D

Comment: Take a look now

Comment: Seems good, so far. But I think the offset of x an y depends on the given icon. Also there could be a `Map` and `Unmap` binding if you like to add. Or maybe transient works, dont know :D

Comment: Oh yess could make sense.

Comment: Thx alot that works for me, though I think I will be better off using the custom titlebar thingy as I wanted that also anyways but glad to see that these two concepts are connected with each other.

Comment: @Atlas I would recommend adding a picture of the result.