# How can I edit the system menu in the Tkinter window Python?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, window, systemmenu

I want to edit the [`system menu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmenu?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in the Tkinter window to show custom options. When I say system menu, I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRaJT.png), the menu that can be opened by right-clicking the title bar of a window, not [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr3gm.png), the dropdown menu in a window.

I want to be able to add as many options as I like, not just the default ones(shown below).

[image]

May I know how I can do that? Thanks.

Comment: I think `tkinter` doesn't has functions for this because it may display directly system, not tkinter. maybe It would be simpler to create own menu from scratch with own titlebar. OR it may need to use other modules - like `win32` in Windows` to modify it.

Comment: Found with Google: [python - Title bar menu in tkinter - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008904/title-bar-menu-in-tkinter)