# Is there a way to make the menu when you right click a window border in windows actually pop up with python/tkinter when using overrideredirect

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

[The Popup Menu Im Talking About.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj6d6.png)

i also havent tried any code. because i cant seem to find what i am looking for and am too stupid to know where to start.

ANY HELP APPRECIATED!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008904/title-bar-menu-in-tkinter

Comment: @ljdyer No, not really. in windows; when you right click (or just left click the icon) the title bar it comes up with a popup menu. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj6d6.png but i am wondering how i can achieve this with overrideredirect in tkinter and if its even possible.