# Tkinter Taskbar/Dock Icon Menu

Tags: python, tkinter

How would I create a contextual/shortcut menu (Right Click menu from taskbar icon) and add a list of commands such as making a new window, list old files opened, etc? Important note:  I want a menu for the icon in the taskbar/dock, not right clicking on the window

Image of desired menu:

[image: Image of menu from Windows]

[image: Image from Mac]

Comment: That would depend on your GUI framework: PyGame, Tk, wxPython. It has absolutely nothing to do with what  `pyinstaller` does.

Comment: I use Tkinter for my GUI's

Comment: @BoarGules How would I create one?

Comment: Even a little bit of research would have led you to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014210/tkinter-app-adding-a-right-click-context-menu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter app adding a right click context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014210/tkinter-app-adding-a-right-click-context-menu)

Comment: @BoarGules I actually have come across that. That question is for right clicking on the application. I want a menu for the icon menu. The icon menu is different