# Should I use _setit even if I get a warning? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

When using _setit I get the following warning in PyCharm:
[image]

Why do I use `_setit`?

I want to add or remove dynamically options to a dropdown list. To do so, I extract the `tk.Menu` object from the `tk.OptionMenu` I defined. And I `add_command` to this `tk.Menu` object. Problem is, when I click on the dropdown list, the element is not selected.

Hence, I use the protected member `_setit` like so:
`MY_MENU.add_command(label=LABEL, command=tk._setit(MY_STRING_VAR, LABEL))`. MY_STRING_VAR is obviously the `tk.StringVar` associated to the `tk.OptionMenu` object defined earlier.

This works perfectly but I'm not allowed to use any `# noqa` in my project and I'm not allowed any weak warnings either. So two questions:

- Is it actually a problem to use a "protected member of a module"? whatever that means?
- Is there any workaround? Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: In my understanding this seems like an implantation error of tkinter in python. *The return value from tk_optionMenu is the name of the menu associated with pathName, so that the caller can change its configuration options or manipulate it in other ways.* [source](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TkCmd/optionMenu.htm)

Comment: I don't think it's an error, the option menu wasn't designed to have items added after it has been created.

Comment: @BryanOakley I find it weird to believe that OptionMenu isn't designed to have items added after it's been created but is designed to have items removed (https://i.imgur.com/FXj43Iv.png)

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows after reading this [discussion](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tk_optionMenu) I feel Bryan is right by the intentional design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, no, you should not be calling the private functions of objects. Being private, it could change on any future release of tkinter. In reality it probably won't, but it's still a bad practice.

The simple solution is to create your own implementation of `_setit`.

Comment: I can't even find how to access the source code of `_setit` so I'm not sure I know how to create my own implementation. Apart from destroying the `OptionMenu` and recreating it, but this sounds not optimal at all?

Comment: You can find the file it's in with this from the command line: `python -c 'import tkinter; print(tkinter.__file__)'`

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Perhaps you want to create your Optionmenu, with a label and a [contextmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12014210) instead.

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't understand why `add_command` would be public if `_setit` isn't though. I don't see a situation where you would to add a label to your dropdown list without being able to interact _at all_ with it.

Comment: @Thingamabobs this is interesting although I'd like to have a dropdown list, and it seems that this isn't really a dropdown list. Also that sounds a bit overkill for me to use. I find it weird to believe that OptionMenu isn't designed to have items added after it's been created (but it's designed to have items removed).

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows: OptionMenu was never designed to be a first class widget. In the original tcl/tk source code it's just a little helper function that combines a menubutton and a menu and a little code to glue them together. That's all it was ever designed to be. I think in most cases you're better off using a `ttk.Combobox`

Comment: What do you mean by `first class widget`?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows: a first class widget means an actual widget - a single object that has standard methods and which behaves like all other widgets.